# QThreadPool reserveThread example

Tags: qt, pyside

Can anyone provide an example of using "reserveThread" and/or "releaseThread" from the QThreadPool class?  I have read the documentation, but I don't really understand when you would use these functions.  Internet searches for examples have come up empty.

I am using PySide, so Python would be preferred, but C++ is also good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These methods are used to interoperate the thread pool with threads that you manually manage.

The thread pool keeps a count of active threads and aims for it not to exceed the maximum number of threads that make sense on given hardware. The `reserveThread` and `releaseThread` change the number of active threads that the pool is aware of. It doesn't directly add nor remove any threads from the pool. **It's not an error that these methods don't return a `QThread`.**

`reserveThread` means: "I'm using a thread that I manage elsewhere, so please consider my thread to be active even though it's not yours (thread pool's).

`releaseThread` means: "I'm not using my thread anymore, feel free to make more of your threads active."

Example: Consider a four logical CPU system. Code is C++.

1. Initially:

   ```
   QThreadPool pool;
   assert(pool.maxThreadCount() == 4);
   assert(pool.activeThreadCount() == 0);
   ```
2. You start a dedicated calculation thread: one core becomes busy. You inform the pool by calling `reserveThread`:

   ```
   MyWorker worker;
   QThread thread;
   worker.moveToThread(&thread);
   thread.start();
   pool.reserveThread();
   assert(pool.activeThreadCount() == 1);
   ```

   The pool is not running any threads itself!
3. You submit four runnables, each taking a while. The pool creates three additional threads to execute them:

   ```
   QAtomicInt act = 0;
   QtConcurrent.run(&pool, [&]{ act.ref(); QThread::sleep(60); act.deref();  });
   QtConcurrent.run(&pool, [&]{ act.ref(); QThread::sleep(60); act.deref();  });
   QtConcurrent.run(&pool, [&]{ act.ref(); QThread::sleep(60); act.deref();  });
   QtConcurrent.run(&pool, [&]{ act.ref(); QThread::sleep(60); act.deref();  });
   QThread::sleep(1);
   assert(pool.activeThreadCount() == 4);
   assert(act.load() == 3);
   ```

   Only three runnables are now active, since one out of four threads is reserved and can't be active: it'd have no CPU to run on, since your thread is busy there.
4. Your calculation thread is done, and you free up one core. You inform the pool by calling `releaseThread`:

   ```
   thread.quit();
   thread.wait();
   pool.releaseThread();
   QThread::sleep(1);
   assert(pool.activeThreadCount() == 4);
   assert(act.load() == 4);
   ```

   Since there was an extra runnable waiting, a thread was activated to get the runnable going.
5. After a minute, all the runnables are done, and there are no more active threads:

   ```
   QThread::sleep(60);
   assert(pool.activeThreadCount() == 0);
   assert(act.load() == 0);
   ```

Comment: Oh, I see now.  And if your thread pool already has 4 running threads (assuming max thread count is 4), and you call `reserveThread`, then the `activeThreadCount` will temporarily go up to 5, even though that is higher than the max thread count.  When one of the running threads finishes, the `activeThreadCount` will go back down to 4.  Thanks for explaining it.